# How can I add a thick borderline after a certain text in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-cell-format

I'm trying to modify my Working Hours Spreadsheet; What I want to do is add a thick borderline after each Sunday, so I can better identify each individual Week of the Month.

[Here's the Masterfile](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dkBcBZU28WA1NMo_KZtxYpbW_pdi3ivg6WTs22xUm6Y/edit?usp=sharing)

Document is in German (I'm Swiss); Sunday = Sonntag

I've tried to do this via conditional formating but there's no option, only to change the colour of the cell.

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].